# want to extract subject, to and body of an email from a text which are separated by :

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout

This is the text message i got from my qrdecoder android application:

```
SMTP:test@test.com:QR demo:Hi admin,
please find the attached
Thanks
test
```

i want to extract emailid, subject i.e QR demo and body of the message.

so that i can call an intent to send email.

```
{
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String aEmailList[] = { "some_email@domain.com"};

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select Email Application"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `java.util.StringTokenizer` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html